# Is there any Collection object Method by which I can Replace a string with some other values?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am looking for any collection object in VBScript,which has the ability to find a particular string in a set of strings(can be Excel row of contents).If search value in the destination string occurs multiple times,then also all the matched value should needs to be replaced by the re-placer one. the functionality should be similar like the `Application.Match()` in the Excel.

**EDIT**

```
  Elements to be removed -> (14,25,99,78)' in an 1D Array
  ArrayList objects hold -> (11,14,23,14,56,67,25,14,112,21,25,14,99,44,33,99,78)
  Fatser process I want which will process the above Arraylist object and give me the 
  list as - > (11,23,56,67,112,21,44,33)
```

Thanks,
Arup

Comment: What's wrong with `For Each` and `Replace`?

Comment: @ZevSpitz I didn't get your point! Can you clarify please here?

Comment: Why not use `Replace` as per Zev's comment? And If you really do not want replace, then you may use perhaps a long routine with `ArrayLists`, `Split`. If you do not want to use `Replace` please clarify why you are looking for an alternative. +1 @Zev Spitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string can be comma delimitted, then you put that into an arrayList using `split`. Then you could search the `ArrayList` since it allows you to add duplicate items.

You could alos use `Replace` in much **convenient** level.

```
Dim strInput as String
strInput = "mystring values are too many values
Replace (strInput, "values", "items")
Msgbox  strInput '-- returns "mystring items are too many items"
```

**Code snippet to remove elements in ArrayList based on values in Array:**
Please change the code according to your data needs. Login remains the same.

```
Sub removeInLists()
Dim vArray As Variant
Dim d As Object
Dim arrayList As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set arrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

'--populate array from Range with deletion keywords
vArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(1).Range("B2:B10"))

arrayList.Add "countries"
arrayList.Add "cities"
arrayList.Add "numbers"
arrayList.Add "hola"
arrayList.Add "decimals"
arrayList.Add "hola"
arrayList.Add "decimals"
arrayList.Add "numbers"

'--put arrayList into the dictionary to get unique values
For i = 0 To arrayList.Count - 1
    If Not d.Exists(arrayList(i)) Then
        d.Add arrayList(i), i
    End If
Next

'--output original arrayList
Sheets(1).Range("C2").Resize(arrayList.Count, _
1) = Application.Transpose(arrayList.toArray)

'-- remove data
For i = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
    '--remove from dictionary
    If d.Exists(vArray(i)) Then
        d.Remove (vArray(i))
    End If
    '--remove from arrayList
    If arrayList.Contains(vArray(i)) Then
        arrayList.Remove vArray(i)
    End If
Next i

'-- if you want you may save it as a array list or keep it as a dicionary or an array
'--vArray = d.Keys

'--output ArrayList
Sheets(1).Range("D2").Resize(arrayList.Count, _
1) = Application.Transpose(arrayList.toArray)

'-- output final dictionary after deletions
Sheets(1).Range("E2").Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.keys)

Set arrayList = Nothing
Set d = Nothing
End Sub
```

Output in Sheet:

[image]

Comment: Can I have a tiny code to understand the logic? I am Confused here. I want to remove some elements from the `ArrayList` object which has been loaded data from an Excel Row. And those elements can be there `0` times and `more than 1` times. Elements that are to be removed from the `ArrayList` are in an 1D array!

Comment: @VBSlover now that's clear. Let's put the `1D Array1` a dictionary. Then it makes the processing quite faster compared to looping through the `Array`.

Comment: concept is good. But Confusion is For any `i` if `vArray(i)` presents more than once in the `ArrayList object` then I think the only one `vArray(i)` will be removed, Am I right?

Comment: Yes I have seen that,But eager to know one thing - Does `Contains()` Collect all the item which is matched with `vArray(i)` or the first match only? Please correct me!

Comment: Does `arrayList.Remove vArray(i)` will remove all the `vArray(i)` from the collection or only the one out of many if present? Please confirm.

Comment: @VBSolver Tukai `contains` doesn't remove all duplicate items. So I sort of injected a `dictionary` object to isolate all unique items from ArrayList. Then **remove items from dictionary** :)

Comment: What I understood that dictionary can eliminate the elements from the destination iff the Item present multiple times,But How `ArrayList' is doing the same,couldn't understand!

Comment: @Tukai the updated code solves the issue. Do take a look. I will also let you know if there's a better, less `loopy` way to do it.

Comment: I am very much confused when I get the final data in the Dictionary itself,then why are we removing the same Item from `ArrayList`? Does `remove` method removing the element which matched from the Arraylist all in one shot or only one item,not caring the other some Items in the `ArrayList`?

Comment: @VBSlover in the above code **IT SHOWS MANY A COMPARISON**. You dont have to remove items from ArrayList here, since Dictionary is doing that. The code is removing all items/duplicate items from ArrayList which matches Array items. But it's doen via an intermediate `dictionary` object.

Comment: now i am clear `99.99%`. Only one data structure is sufficient here which is `Dictionary`.

Comment: I have seen the output just now,Can you now map your code to the each level to 100% understanding?

Comment: In your output sheet how your `D` and `E` column produced means which part of your code produced that, i was trying to map it out due to the two kinds of collection. so asking you if possible for you to map such.